# Why can't Java 11 connect to web site that browsers can?

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, ssl-handshake

I'm trying to connect connect to a website that recently changed their TLS configuration.  It no longer works from Java 11 (nor 17).  It fails at the handshake but the error message doesn't say exactly what went wrong.  The site works in browsers so their admins don't see a problem and won't help.

Is there anything I can do on the Java side to fix this?

```
import java.net.URL

// nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.hudhomestore.gov

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake")
    URL("https://www.hudhomestore.com/Home/Index.aspx")
        .openStream()
        .use { println(it.readBytes().size) }
}
```

Output:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.036 EDT|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.319 EDT|Utilities.java:73|the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=www.hudhomestore.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=www.hudhomestore.com)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.371 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.372 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|INFO|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.382 EDT|AlpnExtension.java:178|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.382 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.384 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.457 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.458 EDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:633|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.458 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.468 EDT|ClientHello.java:642|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "90 C5 39 A6 86 30 CF 64 9A 11 07 3E D1 7E A9 6E CD 61 9C 29 0D E7 64 C3 EA 1F 14 88 F6 01 30 20",
  "session id"          : "87 AC EA CD C3 8D E5 83 30 15 9F 64 28 AE 8A F3 BC 9E A3 23 81 A1 29 4B 41 FE D5 E7 0C BE 07 2A",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=www.hudhomestore.com
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 69 7F BD A5 0C 85 0B 8C   21 09 1E 6E 6B 98 57 EF  i.......!..nk.W.
            0010: 26 3A 77 BE 0B 67 71 5C   9E 02 76 82 38 D2 56 00  &:w..gq\..v.8.V.
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.511 EDT|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.514 EDT|TransportContext.java:352|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1417)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1165)
    at TLSTestKt.main(TLSTest.kt:7)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.515 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1737|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-05-04 13:32:40.515 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1756|close the SSL connection (initiative)
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1417)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1165)
    at TLSTestKt.main(TLSTest.kt:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Strange. Seems as if the server does not support the TLS protocols that are sent int the CH. It seems to be a server issue. Check it's configuration for what protocols and cipher suites it supports.

Comment: Have you troubleshot, e.g., https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-r

Comment: Ugh, this is embarrasing, I thought I had changed it to .gov and tested it but I was still looking at the .com, which does indeed work.  So, PEBKAC, problem exists between keyboard and chair.  Sorry for the bother and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: use .gov not .com in your Java code. The .com site does not even work with HTTPS in the browser.

> The site works in browsers so their admins don't see a problem and won't help.

It does not work in the browser. When trying to access `https://www.hudhomestore.com` in a fresh browser profile (without any cached information) it shows:

[image]

But, `https://www.hudhomestore.gov` (.gov not .com) works and an insecure request to `http://www.hudhomestore.com` (note: http instead of https) works too. The latter returns a permanent redirect (code 301) to (the working) `https://www.hudhomestore.gov`. Since a permanent redirect is cached by the browser it might be that a previous access to (the now non-working) `https://www.hudhomestore.com` also returned the same 301 redirect to the gov site and that when you try to access the non-working site it will use the redirect target from the cache and not actually visit the entered URL first.